# How to show empty object instead of empty struct or nil in Go json marshal

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I need to show json's empty object `{}` when do `json.Marshal()` for a struct pointer. I can only output either `null` value or empty struct value.

If the `person` key is filled with `&Person{}` or `new(Person)`, it will show empty struct like below:

```
{
    "data": {
        "person": {
            "name": "",
            "age": 0
        },
        "created_date": "2009-11-10T23:00:00Z"
    }
}
```

And if we don't initialize it at all, it will show `null`.

```
{
    "data": {
        "person": null,
        "created_date": "2009-11-10T23:00:00Z"
    }
}
```

I want to show `"person": {}`. Is it possible?

Go Playground for the complete code: https://play.golang.org/p/tT15G2ESPVc

Comment: use `omitempty` for the `Person`'s fields. https://play.golang.org/p/o3jWdru_8bC

Comment: another way you could handle this is by using a *non-pointer* wrapper type that embeds your `Person` pointer type, like so: https://play.golang.org/p/EKQc7uf1_Vk

Comment: @mkopriva using `omitempty` for the `Person`'s fields has worked and by far the simplest. 
But it will affect my `Person`'s fields encoding when I want to keep showing, for example, `Person.name` in the marshal result when it is empty

Comment: You can use the alternative in my second comment or you'll have to implement the Marshaler interface on the Response type, I think that's pretty much all the options you're left with.

Comment: this one's a bit ugly but works without having to compromise your original structure. https://play.golang.org/p/1qkSCWZ225j

Comment: @mkopriva thanks for all the answer. I decided to use your second alternative. It's simple enough to implement. You can post your answer to this question so I could accept.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Option **A**, use the `omitempty` tag option on all of the `Person`'s fields and make sure the response's field is allocated before marshaling.

```
type Person struct {
    Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Age  int    `json:"age,omitempty"`
}

// ...

resp.Person = new(Person)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/o3jWdru_8bC

---

Option **B**, use a *non-pointer* wrapper type that embeds the `Person` pointer type.

```
type PersonJSON struct {
    *Person
}

type Response struct {
    Person      PersonJSON `json:"person"`
    CreatedDate time.Time   `json:"created_date"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/EKQc7uf1_Vk

---

Option **C**, have the `Reponse` type implement the `json.Marshaler` interface.

```
func (r *Response) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type tmp Response
    resp := (*tmp)(r)

    var data struct {
        Wrapper struct {
            *Person
        } `json:"person"`
        *tmp
    }
    data.Wrapper.Person = resp.Person
    data.tmp = resp
    return json.Marshal(data)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/1qkSCWZ225j

---

There may be other options...

Comment: Great answer! Option B was just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

In Go, an empty struct by definition assigns zero values to field elements. Eg:  for int 0, "" for string, etc.

For your case, simply comparing to null would work out. Or, you could define an emptyPerson as:

```
 var BAD_AGE = -1
 emptyPerson := &Person{"", BAD_AGE} // BAD_AGE indicates no person
 if person[age] == BAD_AGE {
    // handle case for emptyPerson}
```